# how can i fetch hierarchical data with their refrences in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, tree, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection **Department** as documents with the following format:

```
{
    "department_id" : 1, 
    "title" : "Department1",
    "departmentType_id" : 11
}
{
    "department_id" : 2, 
    "title" : "Department2",
    "departmentType_id" : 12
}
{
    "department_id" : 3, 
    "title" : "Department3",
    "departmentType_id" : 13
}
{
        "department_id" : 4, 
        "title" : "Department4",
        "departmentType_id" : 14
}
{
        "department_id" : 5, 
        "title" : "Department5",
        "departmentType_id" : 15
}
{
        "department_id" : 6, 
        "title" : "Department6",
        "departmentType_id" : 16
}
{
        "department_id" : 7, 
        "title" : "Department7",
        "departmentType_id" : 17
}
```

I have a MongoDB collection **departmentDepartmentRelationship** as documents with the following format:

```
{
    "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 100,
    "relationshipTitle" : "Department1 is parent of Department2",
    "department1_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    "department2_id" : 2,//reference of department with department_id: 2
    "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
}
{
    "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 200,
    "relationshipTitle" : "Department2 is parent of Department3",
    "department1_id" : 2,//reference of department with department_id: 2
    "department2_id" : 3,//reference of department with department_id: 3
    "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
}
{
    "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 210,
    "relationshipTitle" : "Department2 is parent of Department7",
    "department1_id" : 2,//reference of department with department_id: 2
    "department2_id" : 7,//reference of department with department_id: 7
    "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
}
{
    "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 300,
    "relationshipTitle" : "Department3 is parent of Department4",
    "department1_id" : 3,//reference of department with department_id: 3
    "department2_id" : 4,//reference of department with department_id: 4
    "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
}
{
    "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 400,
    "relationshipTitle" : "Department4 is parent of Department5",
    "department1_id" : 4,//reference of department with department_id: 4
    "department2_id" : 5,//reference of department with department_id: 5
    "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
}
{
    "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 500,
    "relationshipTitle" : "Department4 is parent of Department6",
    "department1_id" : 4,//reference of department with department_id: 4
    "department2_id" : 6,//reference of department with department_id: 6
    "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
}
```

Now my model where i define hierarchical structure is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60af33d948d800a1315e96f6"),
    "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" :100,
    "childs" : [ 
        {
            "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 200,
            "childs" : [ //child could by more than one
                {
                    "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 300,
                    "childs" : [//child could by more than one
                        {
                          "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 400,
                               "childs" : []
                        }
                        {
                          "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 500,
                               "childs" : []
                        }

                   ]
                },
               {
                      "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 210,
                        "childs" : []
               }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

is it possible to fetch above hierarchical model in a single query and instead of its references i want  **departmentDepartmentRelationship** JSON object from **departmentDepartmentRelationship** collection ?
My Expected Output is::

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60af33d948d800a1315e96f6"),
        {
        "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 100,
        "relationshipTitle" : "Department1 is parent of Department2",
        "department1_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
        "department2_id" : 2,//reference of department with department_id: 2
        "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
        "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    },
        "childs" : [ 
            {
                {
        "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 200,
        "relationshipTitle" : "Department2 is parent of Department3",
        "department1_id" : 2,//reference of department with department_id: 2
        "department2_id" : 3,//reference of department with department_id: 3
        "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
        "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    },
                "childs" : [ //child could by more than one
                    {
                        {
        "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 300,
        "relationshipTitle" : "Department3 is parent of Department4",
        "department1_id" : 3,//reference of department with department_id: 3
        "department2_id" : 4,//reference of department with department_id: 4
        "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
        "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    },
                        "childs" : [//child could by more than one
                            {
                               {
        "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 400,
        "relationshipTitle" : "Department4 is parent of Department5",
        "department1_id" : 4,//reference of department with department_id: 4
        "department2_id" : 5,//reference of department with department_id: 5
        "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
        "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    },
                                   "childs" : []
                            }
                            {
                              {
        "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 500,
        "relationshipTitle" : "Department4 is parent of Department6",
        "department1_id" : 4,//reference of department with department_id: 4
        "department2_id" : 6,//reference of department with department_id: 6
        "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
        "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    },
                                   "childs" : []
                            }

                       ]
                    },
                   {
                           {
        "departmentDepartmentRelationshipId" : 210,
        "relationshipTitle" : "Department2 is parent of Department7",
        "department1_id" : 2,//reference of department with department_id: 2
        "department2_id" : 7,//reference of department with department_id: 7
        "rootParentDepartment_id" :1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
        "rootParentDepartment_id" : 1,//reference of department with department_id: 1
    },
                            "childs" : []
                   }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

i'm an absolute beginner in mongoDB , i would be very thankful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Not possible. MongoDB counts with [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) which may help you if you change your data little bit. However, how deep your hierarchy can be?

Comment: Thanks @Valijon
please suggest how can i change data ? 
and maxDepth could be 5 or 6

Comment: Actually my data is large and our users have multiple roles and for each role we are allowed to give certain legs of model that's why we're trying to fetch whole model in a single attempt and thus we can save resources too .